# Why is a watched object not updating in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know there are a number of questions like this one but this one is a little different. I took a a look at [reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) and think I have a fair understanding on the subject, one thing I cannot understand though is this:

**tl;dr**

Why does a watched property register changes when initialized with `currentValue = Object.assign=({}, currentValue, initValue)` but not with a direct assignment `currentValue = initValue;`?

I have a registered object, `scoreRules` on the model of my vue component

In the `mounted` hook,

1. I reinitialize the model's `scoreRules` using

`this.$data.scoreRules = initScoreRules;`

(`initScoreRules` is passed in as a prop but I declared it as a local
variable below for the purpose of this question).

2. watch `scoreRules` for changes and log "score has been changed" when the object changes.

This snippet shows this scenario

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      scoreRules: {
        type: "number",
        minimum: null,
        maximum: null
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
  let initScoreRules = {type: "number"};
    this.$data.scoreRules = initScoreRules;
    this.$watch('scoreRules', ()=>{console.log("score has been changed")}, {deep: true});
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <span>Minimum score</span>
    <input type="number" name="minimumScore" v-model.number="scoreRules.minimum" />
</body>

</html>
```

Now, when I type something into the input, the watch does not catch this change and nothing is logged to the console.

If I now reinitialize `scoreRules` using
`this.$data.scoreRules = Object.assign({}, this.$data.scoreRules,  initScoreRules);`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data() {
    return {
      scoreRules: {
        minimum: null
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let initScoreRules = {};
    this.$data.scoreRules = Object.assign({}, this.$data.scoreRules,  initScoreRules);
    this.$watch('scoreRules', () => {
      console.log("score has been changed")
    }, {
      deep: true
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app2">
    <span>Minimum score</span>
    <input type="number" v-model.number="scoreRules.minimum" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

the changes are registered and the output is logged to the console. Why? I suspect it has something to do with the internals of JS itself but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: Objects are reference type. This is why you need to clone an object with `Object.assign` instead of just pointing to an existing one with `=`. When you create a new object Vue has a chance of setting up its reactive environment for the object and its properties.

Comment: I see. Doing a direct assignment with `=` will point to an non-reactive object, and thus changes to that are not registered. Seems obvious now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial object contained properties `minimum` and `maximum`. Then, in `mounted`, you do this:

```
let initScoreRules = {type: "number"};
this.$data.scoreRules = initScoreRules;
```

Which means now the `scoreRules` object does not have those properties.

Vue can only observe changes to properties that are either:

- pre-defined in `data()` (which you did but then un-did in `mounted`)
- set with `Vue.set()` / `this.$set()`
- present on an object that is assigned to a reactive property.

The last point is also the explanation why the second example works: Here, essentially you do this (leavin out the Object.assign verbosity because it is distracting):

```
this.$data.scoreRules = { minimum: null };
```

This property will be reactive.

Read more here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Thanks @Linus. Summed up perfectly.